# React useState to change color not working

Tags: reactjs, svg, state

I have a map of a country (SVG) and I want to highlight a province/state when I hover over it, changing its color/fill. I implemented this but the problem is that onMouseEnter highlights the entire map not just the state I selected.
What I want to do is pass the id of the state/province so that only that state will be highlighted. How can I add it to this or elsewhere:

```
onMouseEnter={() => setColor("yellow")}
```

The functional component:

```
function ColorOnHover() {
const [color, setColor] = useState("#FFF8DC");
return (
<svg>
   <polygon
        id="Paris"
        fill={color}
        stroke="#010101"
        stroke-width="2"
        onMouseEnter={() => setColor("yellow")}
        onMouseOut={() => setColor("#FFF8DC")}
        stroke-miterlimit="10"
        points="1494.844,491.41 ...  />

 <polygon
        id="Azur"
        fill={color}
        stroke="#010101"
        stroke-width="2"
        stroke-miterlimit="10"
        points="638.381,931.285 .../>
  </svg>

  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have the polygon specifically for the country's capital — you have nothing to highlight. Please provide more specific example.

Also, you could solve the problem with pure CSS: just assign a class to all the polygons that are needed to be highlighted and add the :hover styles to that class that highlight a polygon the way you want.

...

UPD:
Then you could try to use setState saving an id of the province and set fill property in polygon tag according to the current selectedId, something like that:

```
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null)

...

<polygon
  id="Paris"
  fill={selectedId === 'Paris" ? 'yellow' : ''}
  onMouseEnter={() => setSelectedId('Paris')}
  onMouseOut={() => setSelectedId(null)}
  ...
/>
```

That's kinda explicit but you could start with something like that.

You should also try the pure CSS solution:

```css
.highlightable:hover {
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<polygon
  id="Paris"
  class="highlightable"
 />
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. What do you mean by "the country's capital"? The map is made up of multiple polygons. Each province is in its own polygon. I posted another polygon for another province to clarify

Comment: Then you could try to use setState saving an id of the province and set fill property in <polygon/> tag according to the current selectedId, something like that:

const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null)

...

<polygon
  id="Paris"
  fill={selectedId === 'Paris" ? 'yellow' : ''}
  onMouseEnter={() => setSelectedId('Paris')}
  onMouseOut={() => setSelectedId(null)}
  ...
/>

Comment: ok thank you but that's what I want to know how to implement!

Comment: If I got your problem right — you were filling all the polygons with the same color, thus you've had the situation when all the map is highlighted. Check the updated answer for some possible solutions.

Comment: @Kotfenum thank you. I actually followed your second recommendation to use a css class. It's so much easier and obvious I don't know why I haven't thought about it!

Comment: @omar You're welcome :) Just wanted to clarify what you have exactly, glad I've helped you!

Answer (score 1):

Solution with css:
1. Add class attribute to svg

```
<svg className="country" ...>
```

2. Create and import css file

   svg.country > polygon { fill: #FFF8DC; }
   svg.country > polygon:hover { fill: yellow; }

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable which basically sets color and passed it in polygon component. Also, use onMouseLeave() instead of onMouseOut().

```
....
const [color, setColor] = useState("#FFF8DC");

const styles = {
 color: color
};

<polygon
  id="Paris"  
  style={styles}
  onMouseEnter={() => setColor("yellow")}
  onMouseLeave={() => setColor("#FFF8DC")}
  ... 
/>
```

)